# Android studio remotely access files from android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im new in android developing, just wondering if i could remotely access android files, like download and upload file to it? like airdroid . is their any opensource project that i could just integrate it to my project?

thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Try learning about Java File IO/ NIO, which is part of the Java SE, which is independent from android dev.
Here's a link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-io

```
     // reading from a file, and printing out its contents.
          String fName = "text_file.txt";
    // get the BufferedReader from the input stream of the file.
    try {
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fName));
        String line;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bReader.close();


    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}